# PHP Regex expert needed - find text within string but with wildcard

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, wildcard, strpos

I have code currently that matches

```
$data=["as much as I like oranges, I like bananas better",
"there's no rest for the wicked",
"the further I move from my target, the further I get",
"just because I like that song, does not mean I will buy it"];

 if (stripos($data[1], 'just because I') !== false) {
      $line=str_ireplace('just because I','*'.just because I.'*',$data[1]);
      break;
  }
```

This way simply matches any sentence that contains that text. But what I want it to do is match with a wild card so it can detect a sentence pattern. So for example it can detect:

```
"just because I... (<<any text in between>>) ...does not mean..."
```

Hope this is understandable. It also needs to match where the text occurs in the sentence and mark it by adding * to the start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of `str_ireplace`:

```
$data = ["as much as I like oranges, I like bananas better",
         "there's no rest for the wicked",
         "the further I move from my target, the further I get",
         "just because I like that song, does not mean I will buy it",
         "the further I move from my target, the further I get"];
$pattern = '/(.*)(just because I .* does not mean)(.*)/i';
$replacement = '$1*$2*$3';
foreach ($data as $data_) {
  $line = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data_, -1, $count)."\n";
  if ($count > 0) {
    break;
  }
}
echo $line;
```

Will return:

```
*just because I like that song, does not mean* I will buy it
```

The `count` variable will contain the number of replacements made, as per the documentation. I added it because it looks like you want to break out of the loop after the first replacement is made.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks very much.